# How do make make subroutine parameter as readwrite

Tags: raku

Suppose I have a subroutine that swaps two given parameters. It logically needs to have read write parameters.

```
sub swap($l, $r)
{
   my $tmp = $l;
   $l=$r;
   $r=$tmp;
}
```

I get the error:

> Cannot assign to a read only variable ($l) or a value

I don't think I can try `\$param` like in perl5.

I think I should try something with `:=` but the documentation doesn't mention anything about the function parameters.

How do I pass parameter as a reference to this subroutine so that I can change its value?

Comment: It is a bit hidden, but there is documentation for this: https://docs.perl6.org/type/Signature#Parameter_Traits_and_Modifiers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```perl6
sub swap ( $l is rw, $r is rw ) {
   ($r,$l) = ($l,$r)
}
```

```perl6
my $a = 1;
my $b = 2;

swap $a, $b;

say $a; # 2;
```

```perl6
my @a[2] = 1,2;

swap |@a;

say @a; # [2 1]
```

---

You can use `reverse` as well for what you are trying to accomplish.

```perl6
my $a = 1;
my $b = 2;

($a,$b) .= reverse;

say $a; # 2
say $b; # 1
```